# asp.net mvc dynamically set login page link on logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have asp.net web application where users need to login from specific login url.
Basically login url is same but there is one id in login url like
www.abc.com/login/uniqueid, 
whenever user gets logout I need to redirect user to www.abc.com/login/uniqueid.

I am using asp.net identity for registration/login.

Can I override authentication attribute and set login url when user is unauthorized and redirect to particular url based on cookie value (cookie I can create on log in)?

On logout button click i can read data from cookie and redirect properly , issue is when user gets automatically logged out

Comment: what is the purpose, anyway? are you trying to track users login/logout? or present them with user-specific page for logout?

Comment: Purpose is user specific login url. So once i login from my url on logout I must see same url in browser.

Comment: purpose, purpose, purpose... WHY do you want to do that? what is the ultimate goal?

Comment: requirement is that when user login along with id/password user's login url unique will be validated also

Comment: Is this a "security" feature? what vector of attack does this mitigate?

Comment: at now this is the requirement based on old website

Comment: The question still stands with the shareholders in your project - what security risk does this mitigate? I don't know what security risk that can fix, I doubt that this fixes anything, only adds complexity and consumes dev-resources. So I suggest you go to project manager and question this requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Identity does not require you to have any specific logout page. By default it is `LogOff` action in `AccountController` where you can redirect user whenever you like.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {

        var logoutId = "blah"; // get your parameters from cookie 

        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return RedirectTo($"~/myLogout/{logoutId}");
    }
```

However, login link is static and is set on application startup for everyone. You can add parameters or cookies in action that representing login page, but you can't change login url [without significant amount of work].

Comment: I have same login page on logout but need it with particular querystring